# Using react-hot-reload and react-router-config

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-hot-loader

When using configuration example for renderRoutes(), react-router-config (react router),  rect-hot-reload stops working and just resets the browser on every change. For example hot reload still works for my Navigation component but not for my routes components(Home, Feature). How do I fix this? I am using react-hot-reload v4, but it is the same thing with v3 also.

**app.js**

```
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Scenes />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**Scenes.jsx**

```
const Scenes = () => (
  <div id="sceneContainer">
    <Navigation />
    {renderRoutes(routes)}
  </div>
)

export default hot(module)(Scenes)(url)
```

**Routes**

```
const routes = [
  {
    component: RouteComponents,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: Home,
        key: 'home',
        exact: true
      },
      {
        path: '/feature',
        component: Feature,
        key: 'feature'
      },
    ],
  },
]

export default routes(url)
```

**RouteComponents**

```
const RouteComponents = (props: Props) => (
  <div id="routeContainer">{renderRoutes(props.route.routes)}</div>
)

export default RouteComponents
```